# Snort report - 1000+ alerts in 1 minute from port 5060

Tags: snort

I woke up this morning and could see over 1000+ of these alerts.

They came in the time space 23:34 - 23:35.
Can anybody tell me what that was about and should I be worried for an eventual DDoS attack?

I am running pfsense and behind that box I have my LAN and a NIC where my server is in a separate environment.

[image: Snort Alter]

Comment: There isn't a lot for us to go on - the source port is 5060, which is SIP/VOIP, and it's coming from Portugal. Is there anything else you can tell us?

Comment: In general, 1000 bad connections in a minute, which then stop, isn't that big of a deal. Without any further data, I might say that someone misconfigured their VOIP server for a moment.

Comment: I have tried to identify the source and he is hiding behind a proxy. That is actually the only thing I know for sure.

My firewall and system logs doesn't show any signs of brute force or any "bad Behavior" activity.

Comment: Most likely it was already blocked by the firewall before it even reached snort, so I don't think it's anything to worry about. If it were a DDos attempt, it would last a lot longer than 1 minute. Snort in general generates tons of alerts, most of which are safe to ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bad configured scanning(attempting) of the communications compagny in Portugal. Since the ip-range might be the same as yours. Or they misconfigured some other connection ip's.

Nevertheless i don't think this commucation compagny is trying to hack you. Unless you have valuable information ;).

Greets

Samuel

More info:

```
inetnum:        87.196.128.0 - 87.196.255.255
netname:        NOS
descr:          NOS COMUNICACOES S.A.
country:        PT
admin-c:        NVSA1-RIPE
tech-c:         NVST1-RIPE
status:         ASSIGNED PA
mnt-by:         IP-MNT
source:         RIPE # Filtered
```

Wikipedia Source Nos communications:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOS_Comunica%C3%A7%C3%B5es

Comment: that is also my conclusion :D